# 20 people in an excursion

Tags: combinatorics

20 people are going to participate in an excursion. They will be transferred to their destination by car. The travel guide has shared them in the available cars in such a way that the maximum number of people is seated in each car (but no more than 5) and also any two people in each car know each other. What is the maximum number of pairs of people who know each other will participate in the excursion?

I am a bit confused:
If for every (say) 5 people in each car, any 2 know each other, we have 5C2=10 pairs, right? 
Then what?

Apologies but I am not very familiar with combinatorics!

Comment: I'm confused too - by the statement of the problem. If each of the $20$ people knows each of the others then you can put them in $4$ cars with $5$ people each. That would seem to give the maximum you ask for - the total number of pairs. If noone knows anyone else then you need $20$ cars with one person in each.

Comment: Actually we know that eventually the maximum number of people who were placed in each car was 5.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help. If you insist on $5$ in every car and you want the _minimum_ number of pairs who know each other then the answer is $4$ groups of $5$, where each group is all friends. So $4 \times 5C2$ pairs.

Comment: I do not insist, this is the problem's narrative. For example, one car may have 5, another 4 and so on, so as to satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum case is when every person knows every other person other than himself.

This is the same as the number of distinct pairs we can make in a set of $n$ elements, which is $$\binom n2 = \frac{n(n-1)}2$$

So among $20$ people, we'd have

$$\frac{20(20-1)}2 = 190$$ pairs of people who know each other, at maximum.